# Can someone help with GAMESS input files for heavy atom calculations (MoS2, WS2, etc.)?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, computational-chemistry, transition-metals, semiconductors

I'm doing computational research on transition metal dichalcogenides for my chemistry class and I want to calculate a transition state optimization for the reaction $\ce{MoS2 +N^- -> MoSN + S^-}$. However the geometry optimizations refuse to converge after 200 iterations. This is being done with a MCP-TZP Data Set within GAMESS on WebMO. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should give some more details on the job you are running so anyone acquiented with GAMESS can give you some advide.

Comment: Sibling site [matter modelling](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/) may be an audience more suitable because your question then may be tagged by [gamess](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gamess) for either GAMESS(US) or GAMESS(UK).

Comment: Generally I agree that it is more suitable for [mattermodeling.se], but I'm not sure the question is complete enough. Maybe add an input for what you currently doing. Also, it could be a chemical issue and not a program issue. Is this a known state? What is you initial guess for the TS based on?

Comment: MоS2 isn't a molecular compound, you should use a solid-state modeling software like quantum espresso instead